# Ignoring a folder when building the nextjs app

Tags: next.js

When building the nextjs app I want to ignore everything under the externals folder.

I have added this but my 'npm run build' still fails. I want to ignore everything under the 'externals' folder which is located in the root folder of the project.

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = { 
  output: 'standalone',
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /.*externals.*/, // I also tried /externals\/.*/ and /externals/
      loader: "ignore-loader",
    });

    return config;
  },
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Error when creating the build

```
$ npm run build

[...]
Failed to compile.

./externals/helpers.ts:59:29
Type error: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: The issue probably isn't webpack but typescript that tries to check the file while you have type errors. Exclude the file or the entire directory in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @FabioNettis that was exactly the problem. Thanks! 

If you put that as an anser I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue probably isn't webpack but typescript that tries to check the file while you have type errors. Exclude the file or the entire directory in your `tsconfig.json`. That would be done like this:

```json
// your tsconfig.json file
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... your compiler options
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/example-nested"]
}
```